# Parametric & Trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

$$x=7\sin(t)+\sin(7t)$$
$$y=7\cos(t)+\cos(7t)$$
How would I solve this one out? I have to simplify the two enough to graph it.

I squaring the two and adding them together, but I hit a roadblock:

$$x^2+y^2=50+7\sin(t)\sin(7t)+7\cos(t)\cos(7t)$$
I don't know how I would simplify that to the point where I could graph it.

Comment: **Hint**: $\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A)$ and $\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$

Comment: OOOHHH Thank you so much I always forget about the double angle formulas

Comment: @RainiervanEs, I get stuck again after that step.
$$x^2+y^2=50+7sin(8t)$$

Comment: Yes, I was already thinking of that.. I think it will be easier to just plug in values for $t$ and sketch the graph that way. You can look here (http://i.stack.imgur.com/fFgnq.png) to see if you sketched it the right way.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help @RainiervanEs.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $x'=x-7\sin t$, $y'=y-7\cos t$. What curve would this produce, and what does this substitution represent?